# Java Gridworld How could I change the act of one Actor?

Tags: java

Hi I am working with the Gridworld. I have a class named `Cow` and it is the subclass of another subclass `Animal`.

This class moves an image of a cow through a grid. Every step is one year for the Cow and in every step that the Cow makes, there is a 0.16666 posibility that a new Cow could be created in a free adjacent field.

Now I try to create another class `Calf`, which is also a subclass of `Animal`. This class shouldn't allow that the newborn Cows are immediatly Cows. Instead, the newborn should be Calf till they are 4 Years(Steps). How could I change it?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import gridworld.framework.actor.Actor;
import gridworld.framework.grid.Grid;
import gridworld.framework.grid.Location;
import Hausaufgabe.Cow;

public class Calf extends Animal{

    public void Act()
    {
        Grid<Actor> gr = getGrid();
        ArrayList<Location> actors = gr.getOccupiedLocations();

        super.act();

        for (int ii=0; ii < actors.size(); ii++)
        {
            Actor actor = gr.get(actors.get(ii));
            Location Loc = actor.getLocation();

            if ((actor instanceof Cow) && this.getAge()<5)
            {
                actor.removeSelfFromGrid();
                Calf calf = new Calf();
                calf.putSelfInGrid(gr,Loc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: You should think of how Calf::Act should be called when you birth cows. Maybe your `Cow` should return a `Calf` (instead of a Cow) with the given probability. Then, you can replace that Cow instance when its year is greater than 4.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was thinking about it, but I thought, maybe there is another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to make the cow move. And when there is the event of a calf being born a new calf is set to the adjacent position. When the calf itself gets to the age of 5, it will be replaced by a new instance of Cow. And cows are always starting with age 5.

However, this solution shows that being a `Cow`or `Calf` is more an attribute of that Animal. But these solutions are making it way more complex. Below is a concept of how such a "rebirth" could be implemented.

```
class Animal {
  protected int age;

  protected void birthday() {
   age++;
  }
}

class Cow extends Animal {

  public Cow() {
     age = 5;
  }

  public void act() {
    super.act();
    //make the cow move
    birthday();

    if(birthACalf()) {
       Calf calf = new Calf();
       calf.putSelfInGrid(....);
    }
  }
}

class Calf extends Animal {

  public void act() {
    super.act();
    birthday();

    if(age >= 5) {
      removeSelfFromGrid();
      Cow cow = new Cow();
      cow.putSelfInGrid(....);
    }
  }
}
```